# Bijection of sets with cartesian product?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Show that given two bijections:
$$f: A \rightarrow \{ 1,...,m \}$$
$$g: B \rightarrow \{ 1,...,n \}$$
there exists a bijection:
$$A \times B\rightarrow \{ 1,...,mn \}$$

**What have I tried so far?**
So, I know that for there to be  a bijection the function must be both injective and surjective. I figured to prove this, I must show both. So I thought I may need to construct the bijection using a table and showing these but I'm not sure if this would be best?

Comment: Hint: think of $A \times B$ as the $mn$ vertices on an $m \times n$ grid laid out using $f$ to get the $x$-coordinates and $g$ to get the $y$-coordinates. You need a way of listing those vertices in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**
Let us denote $[k] = \{1, 2, \cdots, k\}$. Note that $\alpha: A \times B \to [m] \times [n]$ defined by $\alpha(a, b) = (f(a), g(b))$ is a bijection (why?). Thus, we only need to find a bijection from $[m] \times [n]$ to $[mn]$.

To do this, let us order elements of $[m] \times [n]$ with the rule that
$$(a, b) < (a', b) \iff a < a' \text{ or } (a = a' \text{ and } b < b')$$
in other words, we first compare the first elements, and if they are equal, we compare the second elements. Let us write the elements of $[m] \times [n]$ in order according this rule:
$$(1, 1) \\
(1, 2) \\
\vdots \\
(1, n) \\
(2, 1) \\
\vdots \\
(m, n)$$
...and now we simply can simply map the first element in our list to $1$, the second element to $2$, and so on:
$$(1, 1) \iff 1 \\
(1, 2) \iff 2 \\
\vdots \\
(1, n) \iff n \\
(2, 1) \iff n + 1 \\
\vdots \\
(m, n) \iff mn $$
And in fact you can find a closed form for this bijection (call it $\beta$). To do this, you can note that $\beta(a, b)$ is always $b$ greater than a multiple of $n$, and that $\beta(a + 1, b)$ and $\beta(a, b)$ always differ by $n$, for any $a$ and $b$. Can you proceed from here?

**In summary:** We first found a bijection from $\alpha: A \times B$ to $[m] \times [n]$. Then, we found a bijection from $[m] \times [n]$ to $[mn]$. It follows that $\beta \circ \alpha$ is a bijection from $A \times B$ to $[mn]$.

**Addendum:** Why must $\alpha$ be a bijection?

**Answer:** Suppose it weren't injective. Then we could find $(a, b), (a', b') \in A \times B$ such that $\alpha(a,b) = \alpha(a', b')$. This means that
$f(a) = f(a')$ and $g(b) = g(b')$, but this contradicts the fact that $f$ and $g$ are bijections (and are hence injections).

Suppose it weren't surjective. Then we could find $(x, y) \in [m] \times [n]$ such that no element of $A \times B$ mapped to $(x, y)$. For this to be the case, it would have to be that either there existed no element $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = x$, or that there existed no element $b \in B$ such that $g(b) = y$. But this contradicts either $f$ or $g$'s surjectivity (and thus bijectivity).

Comment: This KIND OF makes sense but I'm still confused. Why is $\alpha (a,b)$ a bijection? I get the steps after this though but I'm still not sure...

Comment: @B24Panther I've added some remarks. Does it make sense now? I also realized there was a typo, it should have read "$\alpha: A \times B \to [m] \times [n]$" instead of "$\alpha: A \times B \to [mn]$." Maybe that confused you, sorry.

Comment: Ahhh I see! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Consider $h : A \times B \rightarrow \lbrace 1, ..., mn \rbrace$ defined for all $(a,b) \in A \times B$ by
$$h(a,b) =(f(a)-1)n + g(b) $$

Show that $h$ is well-defined and bijective.